# openerp7 module conversion for odoo8

Tags: odoo

I'm not a programmer so I would really appreciate if anyone could correct the code for a module to work in odoo 8 that was built for openerp 6.1 & 7
The module should retrieve the incoterms from suppliers and display them on the purchase order.

Here is the code of the module.py:

```
import time

from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class res_partner(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _columns = {
        'incoterm_id': fields.many2one(
                'stock.incoterms',
                'Incoterms',
                help="Incoterm which stands for 'International Commercial"
                     "terms' implies its a series of sales terms which are"
                     "used in the commercial transaction."
                ),
        }
res_partner()

class purchase_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order'
    _columns = {
        'incoterm_id': fields.many2one(
                'stock.incoterms',
                'Incoterms',
                help="Incoterm which stands for 'International Commercial"
                     "terms' implies its a series of sales terms which are"
                     "used in the commercial transaction."
                ),
        }
    def onchange_partner_id(self, cr, uid, ids, part):
        res = super(purchase_order,self).onchange_partner_id(cr, uid, ids, part)
        if not part:
            return res
        part = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr, uid, part)
        res['value'].update({'incoterm_id':part.incoterm_id.id or False})
        return res
purchase_order()`
```

This is the error message I get in odoo 8:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 500, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 517, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 283, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 280, in checked_call
return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 733, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 376, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 948, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 940, in _call_kw
return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 360, in old_api
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 5727, in onchange
record._onchange_eval(name, field_onchange[name], result)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 5661, in _onchange_eval
method_res = getattr(self._model, method)(*args)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/warning/warning.py", line 101, in onchange_partner_id
result =  super(purchase_order, self).onchange_partner_id(cr, uid, ids, part, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: onchange_partner_id() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

Comment: If you want to convert this to new API (v8.0), read this [doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/)

Answer (score 1):

You can continue with writing in old api style in odoo v8, it is totally fine.
Try to change the "onchange" method as following:

```
def onchange_partner_id(self, cr, uid, ids, part,context=None):
    res = super(purchase_order,self).onchange_partner_id(
            cr, uid, ids, part, context=context,
            )
```

I think you are missing the last parameter `context`, which is been supplied in the view file, of `purchase_order_form` view. The `on_change` method is receiving two parameters:

1. Partner ID; and
2. Context from the xml file

and you have not included that last parameter `context` in your definition.

Comment: Hi Hardik and thank you very much for your answer. I don't get the error anymore but the Incoterm is not retrieved in the po. I haven't modified the purchase_order_form view file. Would you like to see the view.xml file of the module instead?

Comment: Hi Mangofunky, 
Is it throwing you any kind of error while fetching the incoterm. Did you checked that the field incoterm is added in the database or not.
Let me know, we can discuss this

Comment: Hi Hardik, yes the incoterm_id column is added in both tables of the database res_partner and purchase_order. Thanks for your time in looking into this.

Comment: Hi Mangofunky,
If possible share your ".py" and ".xml" file, I will look into this and let you know

Comment: Hi Hardik, I posted all the files in the question post above. Many thanks

Comment: @Mangofunky - 
try the following onchange method


` def onchange_partner_id(self, cr, uid, ids, part,context=None):
        res = super(purchase_order,self).onchange_partner_id(cr, uid, ids, part,context=context)
        if not part:
            return res
        part = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr, uid, part)
        res['value'].update({'incoterm_id':part.incoterm_id.id or False})
        return res `

This worked for me and incoterm was fetched into the purchase order incoterm field.

Comment: Thank you very much Hardik. It works on the RFQ & Bid tab which I didn't see as I have a field on the main po screen with Incoterms. If I wanted to show the term on the main screen how would I go about? Anyway it's working now, thanks a lot